# ES6 not supported in Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, ecmascript-6

I'm using Google Closure Compiler and I'm getting the following error:

> ES6_FEATURE: this language feature is only supported in es6 mode: computed property. Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT to enable ES6 features.

The line that triggers this error is this one:

```
var TheCellRef = LeadImport2ExcelLibrary['utils']['encode_cell']({ ['c']: C, ['r']: R });
```

Basically I'm passing an object that I'm creating on the same line. I know I could simply add the support for ES6 in the JavaScript source header but I was wondering why this error is coming up and how to fix it?

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? Pre-ecmascript 6 interpreters would think that you're using arrays as object keys which is not valid.

Comment: Uh? It says it right there in the message: *"this language feature is only supported in es6 mode: **computed property**"* You are using computed properties which is an ES6 feature. A possible solution is to not use computed properties. However, I'm really curious why you used `{ ['c']: C, ... }` if you don't seem to be aware of this feature?

Comment: @FelixKling: it's because I'm using the GCC to generate client files dynamically and since I don't have an extern for the library I'm using (SheetJS.js) I need to make sure the GCC doesn't rename the object keys and the way to do that is to using object string notation instead of object dot notation. That's why { c: C, r: R } doesn't work because after  the compilation c and r will be renamed but ['c'] and ['r'] get converted to dot notation so that the library can still get the object it expects.

Comment: Sure, but `{ ['c']: C }` is invalid in ES5 (which I just assumed you knew ;) )

Comment: I replaced the code by creating an object (var TheObject = {};) and then added 2 lines to add the properties (TheObject['c'] = C; TheObject['r'] = R;) and then passing in that object.

Comment: If your using the [web service](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) add `// @language ECMASCRIPT6`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are using [Computed Property Names](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/LanguageFeatures#computed-property-names) in the literal object:

```
{ ['c']: C, ['r']: R }
```

An es5 compatible replacement might be:

```
var TheCellRef = LeadImport2ExcelLibrary['utils']['encode_cell']({ "c": C, "r": R });
```

Comment: Or simply `{ c: C, r: R }`.

Comment: @FelixKling The quotes are needed on the property names to block renaming.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth: depends on how the code is compiled, but it seems to be the case here, yes.